# Function that returns the sum of the elements of a single row of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, loops, matrix, multidimensional-array, sum

So i have a Python program that creates a 3 x 3 matrix (without using numPy). It contains a function that inputs the elements of the matrix, prints it out, and calculates the sum of a single row of the matrix. The latter is the part i'm having issues with. How would i write the getSumRow function, so that it returns the sum of the elements of a single row of the matrix. The function is passed the matrix and the row index.

```
#Program that creates a 3x3 matrix and prints sum of rows

   def getMatrix():
    A=[[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)] #creating 2d list to store matrix
    for i in range(3): #setting column bounds to 3
        for j in range(3): #settting row bounds to 3
            number=int(input("Please Enter Elements of Matrix A:")) 
            A[i][j]=number #fills array using nested loops
    return A #returns 2d array (3x3 matrix)

def getSumRow(a,row):


def printMatrix(a):
    for i, element in enumerate(a): #where a is the 3x3 matrix
        print(*a[i])
    #accesses the 2d array and prints them in order of rows and columns

def main():
    #includes function calls 
    mat = getMatrix()
    print("The sum of row 1 is", getSumRow(mat,0))
    print("The sum of row 2 is", getSumRow(mat,1))
    print("The sum of row 3 is", getSumRow(mat,2))
    printMatrix(mat)

 main()
```

How can i get it so that when it prints using the getSumRow function, it will print the sum of each row of the matrix individually?

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix like:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 6],
    [5, 8, 7],
    [9, 1, 2]
]
```

You can get a row by indexing (indexes start at 0) into the matrix:

```
matrix[1] # --> [5, 8, 7]
```

Since that's just a list, you can call `sum()` on it:

```
sum(matrix[1]) # --> 20

sum(matrix[2]) # --> 12
```